# Installing m2e connector removes junit integration

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-neon

We've been facing this issue for quite some months now, and we can't seem to find any solutions for it so far (not many relevant threads on the internet about people having the same issues).

My team is using Eclipse. For some of our Maven poms, we need to install a specific m2e connector. The error we get is :

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.12:add-test-source (execution: add-source, phase: generate-sources)
```

Eclipse offers to install an additional connector to fix the issue. It can be installed, and indeed our Maven errors disappear after a restart of the application. The specific plugin to install is **build-helper-maven-plugin**.

However, this installations also has the interesting effect **to completely remove the junit integration from eclipse**. It becomes impossible to run tests, and all of the junit related context / views / perspectives / settings are gone for good.
When trying to install it again, the "Install new software" view indicates that the testing integration is already installed.

Existing junit views now show the following error :

```
Could not create the view: org.eclipse.jdt.junit.ResultView
```

So far our only solution has been to keep a backup of eclipse at all times, and simply replace the whole installation after maven has been run once.

Has this happened to anyone, or can someone point us in the direction on how to fix this?

The issue is reproducable on Neon 1 and 2, both for the default eclipse as well as the RCP developers flavor

[We have tried to get help from the eclipse community but without success so far](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1747401/?srch=m2e%20connector#msg_1747401)

Current eclipse installation : 
[image]

Comment: I have never experienced this. The Eclipse (Neon / Mars / and even Luna) I have has lots of M2E connectors, including the one for the build-helper-maven-plugin, and JUnit integration still works as expected. Not sure what to say here, reinstall from scratch?

Comment: This issue has been seen for several installations of eclipse, on several different computers. Both for eclipse upgrades and fresh installs. I have also seen the same behaviour :S

Comment: Which version of m2e do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have added a screenshot with all versions being used

Comment: If you can reproduce this consistently on your end, can you provide a set of steps with what you're _exactly_ (step by step) doing so that it is possible to reproduce it ourselves? You can even start from which Eclipse you downloaded. What is your OS also (I'm not seeing the images, sorry if it's somehow there...)?